# ContentPage containing list view display very slow on Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

I am not sure whether this is my problem or a problem with Xamarin.
On an iPad my application can load the page which contain a list of data in ListView. 
The View Cell inside the ListView can be slightly complex. It contains a profile image, some smaller icons using, which are using FFImageLoading.

On iPad, when I tap a cell of the first page to go into the next page, which contains a list of data, it loads very smoothly.
On Android, when I tap on a cell to go into the next page, the detection of the tap is slow and the loading time of the ListView also very slow.

Is there anyway enhance the performance? I thought it was the data I loaded from SQLite. However, after I comment out the ItemsSource on ListView, the loading time is fine.

This is the datatemplate I've used for displaying the cell.

```
<ViewCell>
               <ViewCell.View>
                    <StackLayout Spacing="0" Padding="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="10" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                <controls:CircleImage 
                                    Style="{StaticResource profileImageStyle}"
                                    Margin="10, 10, 10, 10"
                                    Source="{Binding Source}"
                                    BorderColor="White"
                                    BorderThickness="2"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center">

                                    <controls:CircleImage.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer  Tapped="OnChildDetailTapped" />
                                    </controls:CircleImage.GestureRecognizers>
                                </controls:CircleImage>

                                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill" Spacing="1" Padding="0,20,0,10" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer  Tapped="OnChildDetailTapped" /> 
                                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <StackLayout
                                        Orientation="Vertical"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                                        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"> 
                                        <Label x:Name="childName" Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Style="{StaticResource normalFont}"> </Label>
                                        <local:ChildInfoIconsView 
                                            Child="{Binding .}"
                                            VerticalOptions="Fill">
                                        </local:ChildInfoIconsView>


                                        <Label 
                                            x:Name="childNotes"
                                            Style="{StaticResource footnoteFont}"
                                            Text="{Binding ChildNotes, StringFormat={x:Static local:AppResources.formatNotes}}" 
                                            IsVisible="{Binding HasChildNotes}">
                                        </Label>
                                        <Label 
                                            x:Name="noPickupReason" 
                                            Style="{StaticResource footnoteFont}"
                                            Text="{Binding NoPickupReason, StringFormat={x:Static local:AppResources.formatNoPickupReason}}" 
                                            IsVisible="{Binding HasNoPickupReason}">
                                        </Label>
                                        <Label 
                                            x:Name="absentReason" 
                                            Style="{StaticResource footnoteFont}"
                                            Text="{Binding AbsentReason, StringFormat={x:Static local:AppResources.formatAbsentReason}}"
                                            IsVisible="{Binding HasAbsentReason}">
                                        </Label> 
                                    </StackLayout>  
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="End">

                                <StackLayout.Padding>
                                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                                        <OnIdiom.Phone>5, 20, 10, 20</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>10, 30, 30, 30</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                    </OnIdiom>
                                </StackLayout.Padding>

                                <Image 
                                    Style="{StaticResource listviewButtonStyle}"
                                    IsVisible="{Binding EnabledSigning, Source={x:Reference page}}" 
                                    Source="ic_action_yes.png"
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    HorizontalOptions="End">
                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer  Tapped="OnAttend" />
                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <Image.Margin>
                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>0, 0, 5, 0</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>5, 5, 20, 5</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        </OnIdiom>
                                    </Image.Margin>
                                </Image>
                                <Image 
                                    Style="{StaticResource listviewButtonStyle}"
                                    IsVisible="{Binding EnabledSigning, Source={x:Reference page}}" 
                                    Source="ic_action_no.png"
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    HorizontalOptions="End">
                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer  Tapped="OnAbsent" />
                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <Image.Margin>
                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>5, 0, 0, 0</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>20, 5, 5, 5</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                        </OnIdiom>
                                    </Image.Margin>
                                </Image>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>

                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
```

[image]

Comment: If there is a lot data, maybe try lazy loading

Comment: The data wasn't that much 9 rows of data but the view cell need to show profile and small icons. The small icons only 24dp

Comment: have you try to downsampled the image?

Comment: yes ... I have no problem with scrolling the list view after recycle element property set. Just when I load first load the page that was slow to show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting a listview caching strategy to improve performance.

[See here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance/) for more details

Be aware though that you may need to jump through some hoops to use RecycleElement with FFImageLoading. The issue is described [here](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-Advanced)

Also, please post your data template so we can see if it can be simplified.

Comment: Yes I have use this RecycleElement, when I realised the scrolling got too slow.. But this doesn't help me from navigation to the page contain the listview.

Comment: Just put a single TapGestureRecogniser on the top level stack layout, rather than several inside the cell. Also you can try binding SelectedItem on the listview rather than using a gesture recogniser.

Comment: The layout in your data template is very complex and uses a load of stack layouts. You should be able to simplify it massively by using a grid with 5 columns. The labels in the second column can stay in a stack layout.

Comment: The icon you see in the image. Can it be grid as well. Currently using stacklayout as well... how much faster when using grid?

Comment: If you look at the performance article, it recommends to use a grid over nested stack layouts https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/deployment-testing/performance/

Comment: You could create a grid with 3 rows and use rowspan=3 on all columns other than the one with the icons. Or use a stack layout in the column with the icons. Test each  for performance

Comment: Thank for your help. I will have to change the layout of those cells.

Comment: I changed to grid but the loading time on that page doesn't seem to have any much different.

Answer (score 0):

**Use RecyclerView**

https://blog.xamarin.com/recyclerview-highly-optimized-collections-for-android-apps/

***OR***

**Use FFImageLoading**

https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading

to optimize and for smoother scroll